# Scroll to bottom not working in IE or FF, only Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

If you press the "Profile" button in the top right, it will scroll to the bottom of the page in Chrome but not in FF or IE. I'm not sure why not. Is it because JS is being blocked?

```
   $("#profile").click(function() {
       $('body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(".anchor-point").offset().top
       }, 2000);
   });
```

http://imdarrien.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $('html, body') instead of $('body') :

```
    $("#profile").click(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(".anchor-point").offset().top
       }, 2000);
   });
```